# How can I nack or reject message after republish to dlq

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

When the consumer throws an exception republishToDlq during the processing of the message and before the manual ack works, but the original queue message is always in the nack state.

#### Environment

`Spring Boot`: `2.1.11.RELEASE`

`Spring Cloud`: `Greenwich.SR4`

`Spring Cloud Stream`: `Fishtown.SR4`

`spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit`: `2.1.4.RELEASE`

#### Yaml config

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          binder: rabbit
          group: ${spring.application.name}_input
          content-type: application/json
          destination: push_message
      rabbit:
        bindings:
          input:
            consumer:
              acknowledge-mode: MANUAL
              exchange-type: topic
              consumer-tag-prefix: ${spring.application.name}_input
              binding-routing-key:  ${spring.application.name}_input
              autoBindDlq: true
              republishToDlq: true
```

#### Result

[Rabbitmq Management Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muo4N.png)

#### Expect

Nack or reject the original the original queue message after republishToDlq.

Is my understanding above correct? If not, please correct me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a Spring AMQP perspective, using MANUAL ack mode means the "application" takes complete responsibility for acking messages.

Again, from a Spring AMQP perspective, republishToDlq is considered a "successful" delivery.

The first question is "what is your use case for using MANUAL"? It is rarely needed and often used mistakenly.

That said, I can see an argument that, again, from a Spring AMQP perspective, the binder is part of the application and we should look at acking the message after publishing to the DLQ in the binder (when the ack mode is MANUAL).

Please open a GitHub new feature issue against the binder and we'll take a look.

In the meantime, the work around is to catch the exception in your listener and ack (not nack) the message before re-throwing the exception.

But, you should consider whether MANUAL acks are really needed.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me. I have submitted the github issue, see [#281](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit/issues/281)